# Добавление выбранных checkboxом данных через массив в определенную запись

Tags: checkbox, php

```
if (isset($_POST['race'])){
$id_race=array();
foreach($_POST['race'] as $key=>$value){
$id_race[] = "('$value')";
}
$res3 = q("INSERT INTO protagonist_book (id_protagonist,id_race) VALUES('',".implode(',', $id_race));
}
```

id protagonist(идентификатор героя) ---> несколько идентификаторов рас(1,3,5)
хочу добавить несколько id_race к определенному id_protagonist.
id protagonist 29 ---> id_race 1,3,5

как это сделать?

Comment: @El_ten, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. И постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за конструктив,изменил и подкорректировал запись...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для связки вам требуется дополнительная третья таблица.
Советую почитать про нормальные формы БД.

Comment: Нашел я решение. Как и сказал Gedweb.Создал третью таблицу,связующую id_race и id_protagonist.